# Merging two rows into one based on common field

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with the following data:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|id        |name        |predicted    |actual         |yyyy_mm_dd|
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|       215|     NirPost|         null|100.10023      |2020-01-10|
|      null|     NirPost|        57145|null           |2020-01-10|
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

I want to merge these two rows into one, based on the `name`. This df is the result of a query which I've restricted to one company and single day. In the real dataset, there is 70~ companies with daily data. I want to rewrite this data into a new table as single rows.

This is the output I'd like:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|id        |name        |predicted    | actual        |yyyy_mm_dd|
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|       215|     NirPost| 57145       |100.10023      |2020-01-10|
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

I've tried this:

```
df.replace('null','').groupby('name',as_index=False).agg(''.join)
```

However, this outputs my original df but with `NaN` instead of `null`.

```
`df.dtypes`:

id          float64
name        object
predicted   float64
actual      float64
yyyy_mm_dd  object
dtype:      object
```

Comment: The column `actual` is a string right?

Comment: It's `float64`.

Comment: can you try `df.groupby('name',as_index=False,sort=False).first()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 that also gives two rows as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you explicitly pass all the columns in the `groupby` with `max` so that it eliminates the null values?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'id':[215,np.nan],'name':['nirpost','nirpost'],'predicted':[np.nan,57145],'actual':[100.12,np.nan],'yyyy_mm_dd':['2020-01-10','2020-01-10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.groupby('name').agg({'id':'max','predicted':'max','actual':'max','yyyy_mm_dd':'max'}).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
      name     id  predicted  actual  yyyy_mm_dd
0  nirpost  215.0    57145.0  100.12  2020-01-10
```

Of course since you have more data you should probably consider adding something else in your `groupby` so as to not delete too many rows, but for the example data you provide, I believe this is a way to solve the issue.

### EDIT:

If all columns are being named as `max_original_column_name` then you can simply use this:

```
df.columns = [x[:-4] for x in list(df)]
```

With the list comprehension you are creating a list that strips the last 4 characters (that is `_max` from each value in `list(df)` which is the list of the name of the columns. Last, you are assigning it with `df.columns =`

Comment: I think I just need to add `yyyy_mm_dd` to the groupby since I'll have the same company multiple times in the base df (two rows per company for every day). Also, your solution seems to work but is there anyway to retain the original column names as they get replaced with  `max({column_name})`

Comment: Oh, sure, I'll edit my answer. However I am not getting that name in the output, but it should easy to work it out.

Comment: I was getting for example `max(predicted)`, `max(actual)` as column names and not `max_predicted`, `max_actual` - this is no longer the case now though. I do instead get an error that `name` is an index and column. Would it be possible to make this transformation without `name` being used as an index?

Comment: Yeah, so I made a mistake because `name` shouldn't have been in the aggregation function. It should be only part of the `groupby` so then you can `reset_index()` to have it. Second edit should be ok now. I simply changed the function to: `df = df.groupby('name').agg({'id':'max','predicted':'max','actual':'max','yyyy_mm_dd':'max'}).reset_index()`